# Subaru Outback 2022 electronic hatch won't open and lock won't latch

Tags: subaru, outback, latch

Our 2020 Subaru Outback rear gate won't open or close and the lock remains in open position. How do I reset it?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To reset the electronic rear latch mechanism, close the gate, press and hold the exterior latch button for 10 seconds. You will feel it re-locking the latch. At this point, the gate will open, close, and lock normally.

You can also reset everything, including the locking mechanism, by disconnecting and reconnecting the battery.